How to convert multi-index pandas data frame into a single index with a new column from one of the indices?
I have a multi-index pandas dataframe as follows


I want to convert it to the following with a new column created from one of the indices

I can do this with a simple for loop but wonder if there is an efficient way of transforming the original data frame to the target data frame?

Please replace the images with text. See Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

Code
use stack + reset_index
order = cur_df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique()
out = cur_df.stack()[order].reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)

Check with example
i make minimal and reproducible example to check code for you:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arr1 = [['Close', 'High', 'Adj Close', 'Open'], ['A', 'AAL']]
idx = pd.date_range('2008-01-02', '2008-01-04', name='Date')
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(arr1, names=['Price', 'Ticker'])
np.random.seed(0)
data = np.random.randint(10, 20, (3, 8))
cur_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=cols)
print(cur_df) # input

order = cur_df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique()
out = cur_df.stack()[order].reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print(out) # output


